# Xcode: Storyboard is missing in Resource Bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard, target

I have added a new target (named "Hortus") to an existing project. This target will use a different storyboard (named "Hortus.storyboard"). I duplicated the existing storyboard as starting point. In my Hortus-Info.plist file I changed the property *Main storyboard file base name* in "Hortus". In the *General* tab of the target "Hortus" I changed the *Main Interface* to "Hortus".

When building the target, there are no errors or warnings. But when I run the app I get the error message 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Hortus' in bundle NSBundle <...>'. I checked the path in the error message and the storyboard is indeed missing in the bundle.

I've checked that the storyboard is added to *Copy Resource Bundles* from the *Build Phases* tab of the target. It is present in this list and it is not indicated in red.

Based on similar questions on StackOverflow from 3 or 4 years ago, I tried the following things. None of these things solved my problem:

- I removed and added the file to the list *Copy Resource Bundles*
- I restarted Xcode
- I cleared the Derived Data directory and restarted
- I'm using localization. I tried disabling the languages and activating them again.

I have no clue what I am missing and how I can solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated.